# How make Autocomplete with wp_query in post_type attachment

Tags: search

This is my list of arguments to search for the attached files and I need to make it take references, for example, if my file is called banner, when placing the letter b, said file and others that may contain this same letter appear without having to place everything. the name I can not find the solution

```
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {
        $value = $_GET['search'];
    }
    
    if (isset($_GET['select']) && !empty($_GET['select'])) {
        $check = $_GET['select'];
    }

$query_images_args = array(
            's' => $value,
            'post_type' => 'attachment', 
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_mime_type' => $check,
            'posts_per_page' => '-1'
        ); 

        $query_images = new WP_Query(  $query_images_args  );
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it's a duplicate of this user's [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/411281/attached-file-how-can-i-work-the-wp-query-to-search-for-related-names).

Comment: Hi, I thought I had deleted my previous question since I did it very badly... and I made this new one because I couldn't find the solution